CUnit framework with visual studio
hello i am trying to use CUnit framework with visual studio i used these command
and there is no errors but the cunit.lib file is not generated in the source/.libs file
is there a solution?
libtoolize

automake --add-missing 

autoreconf

./configure --prefix=/mingw

make

make install

